# Postgres JSONb to XML with tag_name and tag_value

Tags: xml, postgresql, jsonb

I am new to Postgres XML functions. I have a table as below:

```
id  (VARCHAR) | field1 (text) | attributes  (jsonb)     
--------------+---------------+----------------------------------

 123          |   a           |   {"age": "1", "place": "TX"}                 
 456          |   b           |   {"age": "2", "name": "abcdef"}     
 789          |               |       
 098          |   c           |   {"name": "gefd"}
```

Would like to convert it to :

```
 <Company id="123" field="a">
      <CompanyTag tagName="age" tagValue="1"/>
      <CompanyTag tagName="place" tagValue="TX"/>
 </Company>
 <Company id="456" field="b">
      <CompanyTag tagName="age" tagValue="2"/>
      <CompanyTag tagName="name" tagValue="abcdef"/>
 </Company>
 <Company id="789"/>
  <Company id="098" field="c">
      <CompanyTag tagName="name" tagValue="gefd"/>
 </Company>
```

Was able to convert the first two column easily using below but the JSONb has the toughest part:

```
#SELECT xmlelement(name Company, xmlattributes(id as id, field1 as field)) from comp_emp;;
 <Company id="123" field="a"/>
 <Company id="456" field="b"/>
 <Company id="789"/>
 <Company id="098" field="c"/>
```

Please guide me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

Building on @Georges Martin's solution, I wouldn't use a lateral join and a grouping clause, but rather just a nested subquery:

```
SELECT XMLELEMENT(
  NAME "Company", 
  XMLATTRIBUTES(id AS id, field1 AS field), 
  (SELECT XMLAGG(
    XMLELEMENT(
      NAME "companyTag", 
      XMLATTRIBUTES(
        attr.key AS "tagName", 
        attr.value AS "tagValue"
      )
    )
  ) FROM JSONB_EACH_TEXT(attributes) AS attr)
) FROM comp_emp;
```

<sup>([online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=1b9d6ffbb9aac68c14c5585f5e19aa70))</sup>

Comment: Unfortunately if the attributes is an array like below, instead of returning each value, it extracts as a single value:

If the attribute value is :
{"age": "2", "name": ["abc", "def", "ghi"]} 

it returns the value as :
tagValue="[&quot;abc&quot;, &quot;def&quot;, &quot;ghi&quot;]"/>

Comment: @AArun You haven't mentioned that case before, I'd suggest you [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) about it and describe the expected result there.

Comment: Thank you. Have asked again with the updated values under https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64354263/postgres-jsonb-including-array-to-xml-with-key-and-value-and-value

Answer (score 1):

This is a partial solution as I forgot the `field1` column but this:

```sql
SELECT 
 XMLELEMENT(
  NAME "Company", 
  XMLATTRIBUTES(id AS id), 
  XMLAGG(
   XMLELEMENT(
    NAME "CompanyTag", 
    XMLATTRIBUTES(
     (attr).key AS "tagName", 
     (attr).value AS "tagValue"
    )
   )
  )
 ) 
FROM (
 SELECT 
  id, JSONB_EACH_TEXT(attributes) AS attr 
 FROM comp_emp
) AS sub 
GROUP BY id;
```

already returns:

```xml
<Company id="098">
  <CompanyTag tagName="name" tagValue="gefd"/>
</Company>
<Company id="456">
  <CompanyTag tagName="age" tagValue="2"/>
  <CompanyTag tagName="name" tagValue="abcdef"/>
</Company>
<Company id="123">
  <CompanyTag tagName="age" tagValue="1"/>
  <CompanyTag tagName="place" tagValue="TX"/>
</Company>
```