# Postgres JSONb including array to XML with key and value and value

Tags: xml, postgresql

I have a table as below:

```
id  (VARCHAR) | field1 (text) | attributes  (jsonb)     
--------------+---------------+----------------------------------

 123          |   a           |   {"age": "1", "place": "TX"}                 
 456          |   b           |   {"age": "2", "name": "abcdef"}     
 789          |               |       
 098          |   c           |   {"name": ["abc", "def", "ghi"]}
```

Would like to convert it to :

```
 <Company id="123" field="a">
      <CompanyTag tagName="age" tagValue="1"/>
      <CompanyTag tagName="place" tagValue="TX"/>
 </Company>
 <Company id="456" field="b">
      <CompanyTag tagName="age" tagValue="2"/>
      <CompanyTag tagName="name" tagValue="abcdef"/>
 </Company>
 <Company id="789"/>
  <Company id="098" field="c">
      <CompanyTag tagName="name" tagValue="abc"/>
      <CompanyTag tagName="name" tagValue="def"/>
      <CompanyTag tagName="name" tagValue="ghi"/>
 </Company>
```

With help of @bergi and @Georges Martin under [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64295814/postgres-jsonb-to-xml-with-tag-name-and-tag-value) was able to convert the non array using below query:

```
SELECT XMLELEMENT(
  NAME "Company", 
  XMLATTRIBUTES(id AS id, field1 AS field), 
  (SELECT XMLAGG(
    XMLELEMENT(
      NAME "companyTag", 
      XMLATTRIBUTES(
        attr.key AS "tagName", 
        attr.value AS "tagValue"
      )
    )
  ) FROM JSONB_EACH_TEXT(attributes) AS attr)
) FROM comp_emp;
```

However the array values displays as below:

```
 <Company id="098" field="c">
      <CompanyTag tagName="name"tagValue="[&quot;abc&quot;, &quot;def&quot;, &quot;ghi&quot;]"/>
```

I do not want to mention the key ("tagName") specifically in the query as this may vary. Assuming that this is caused due to JSONB_EACH_TEXT extracting the outermost values. Is there an alternative?

Please guide me in the right direction.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the example. I had feared at first that you expected to get `<CompanyTag tagName="name" tagValue="abc" tagValue="def" …/>`, which I guess is not possible. Repeated `<CompanyTag>`s however is easy.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need an extra `jsonb_array_elements_text` extracting the values if you're dealing with an array. Done with a lateral join:

```
SELECT XMLAGG(
  XMLELEMENT(
    NAME "CompanyTag", 
    XMLATTRIBUTES(
      attr.key AS "tagName", 
      values.element AS "tagValue"
    )
  )
) FROM jsonb_each(attributes) AS attr,
LATERAL jsonb_array_elements_text(CASE jsonb_typeof(attr.value)
  WHEN 'array' THEN attr.value
  ELSE jsonb_build_array(attr.value)
END) AS values(element)
```

<sup>([online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=d661a53853b7b207e5ed58527cc3c283), with complete query)</sup>

Comment: @AArun Glad to have helped! You might want to accept the answers again.